# Loadbalancer Service in AKS is now working. Please see the screenshot

Tags: kubernetes, azure-load-balancer

I have created the load balancer service in AKS, my container is working fine, when i am running by using docker run command. Here, are the screenshot of my kubernetes dashboard and service is also working but I am not able to access the ip.

[Kubernetes service is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8l8x.png)

I am using my own image ashishrajput194/finreg-frontend:v1 and it is having angular project and I am using nginx as web server. Here, are the config file of nginx.

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/json           max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
  expires $expires;
  gzip  on;
}
```

Please help to resolve my issue.

Comment: What you mean by it's not working? How did you tested and what have you tried so far? Also, please, avoid using screenshots, they are bad for stackoverflow as they are not indexable, copiable and so on.Please take a look at [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: As I am new here and I don't have enough experience so, I have attached the screenshot. For future question posts, I will not use any screenshots. I have tested my service on AKS in azure.